# Finding area bounded by a parametric curve

Tags: calculus, integration, area, curves

I'm trying to find the area bounded by the curve $x^3=ay^4 - x^2y$.

First, I have an example of a solution to finding area of the following curve: $x^3 + y^3 = 3axy, a > 0$.
In the solution, they first  express the equation parametrically as following. Let $t=\frac{y}{x}$. Then $$x = \frac{3at}{1 + t^3}, y = \frac{3at^2}{1 + t^3}.$$
And then they say that the curve describes a loop if the parameter $t$ ranges from $0$ to $+\infty$, which I don't understand why (like, how do you arrive at that). Here's the picture they've shown:
[image: loop bounded by a curve]
And I can also see this if I put the parametric graph in Desmos, let $t$ be between $0$ and some arbitrarily large number (the $+\infty$ part of the range described) and then slide $a$:[image: gif of the loop with a varying parameter]
Now let's go back to my original equation. If I, in the same fashion, set the parameter $t=\frac{y}{x}$, the equation would be the following: $$x=\frac{1+t}{at^4}, y=\frac{1+t}{at^3}.$$

Next I've tried playing around with different ranges of $t$ in Desmos in order to obtain a loop similar to the one in the first gif, and I've managed to do that if I let $t$ be between an arbitrarily large negative number ($-\infty$) and $-1$:[image: gif of another loop with a varying parameter]

But I really have no idea how to rigorously proof that in that range of the parameter $t$, the curve describes a loop.
All we need to do then is calculate the area by this formula:
$$S=\frac{1}{2}\int_{t_1}^{t_2} |y(t)x'(t)-x(t)y'(t)|dt,$$ where $t_1$ and $t_2$ are the bounds of the range for which the parameter makes the curve describe a loop. Still, the question is: how do you determine that range? Because if I put one of the bound of the range for my equation $0$, the the integral would diverge, but with $-1$ it doesn't.

Comment: This are not polar coordinates

Comment: oh yeah, my bad

Comment: Are you sure the curve is closed?  I don't think it is.

Comment: Well the area should converge to some finite number times $a$

Comment: How do you know the area should converge to some finite number times $a$?  You've not even plotted the equation in question.

Comment: I did in the second gif

Comment: Please show your equations for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ *for the problem at hand*... not the simpler problem at the top.

Comment: But I did show them after the words "Now let's go back to my original equation"

Comment: I find it somewhat strange that, for all the attention given to your question, so few have actually understood what you asked, let alone attempted to answer it.  Even the currently upvoted answer does not answer your question!  Please see my response below.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I haven't fully grasped your answer yet, but at first glance it does seem to answer my question so I'm going to try to understand it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some geometric intuition that we can apply here.

In the example you provide (which describes a curve called a folium), the parametrization $t = y/x$ has a geometric interpretation:  it means $t$ is a parameter that describes the *slope* of the corresponding parametrized point $(x(t), y(t))$ relative to the origin.

In other words, for each $t$, the point $(x(t), y(t))$ lies on the line $y = tx$, *by construction*.  So if the implicit equation is $x^3 + y^3 = 3axy$ and the parametrization yields $$(x(t), y(t)) = \left(\frac{3at}{1+t^3}, \frac{3at^2}{1+t^3}\right), \tag{1}$$ then we can see that when $a > 0$, $(x,y)$ will be located in the first quadrant whenever $0 < t < \infty$ since $x > 0$ and $y > 0$ for such $t$; moreover, the line $y = tx$ on this interval of $t$ sweeps across the first quadrant, and because of uniqueness, there is only one point being chosen to be on the curve for each such line; i.e., the curve is simple with no self-intersection on this interval.

Finally, the fact that $(x(0), y(0)) = (0,0)$ and $\lim_{t \to \infty} (x(t),y(t)) = (0,0)$ implies that the curve is closed.

Having established this, the question of the curve's behavior for $t < 0$ is of course easier to understand.  When $-1 < t < 0$, the line $y = tx$ makes an angle with the positive $x$-axis between $-\pi/4$ and $0$.  So on this $t$-interval, these lines will sweep out points on the curves in the second quadrant.  Indeed, we can formally see this:  when $-1 < t < 0$, then $1 + t^3 > 0$ and again, for $a > 0$, $x(t) < 0$ but $y(t) > 0$.  As $t \to -1^+$, $x \to -\infty$ and $y \to +\infty$.

When $-\infty < t < -1$, the line $y = tx$ sweeps out angles from $-\pi/2$ to $-\pi/4$, and now we are in the fourth quadrant, since $1 + t^3 < 0$ hence $x(t) > 0$, $y(t) < 0$.

This also explains why the folium is reflected through the origin when $a < 0$.

For your curve, the parametrization is $$(x(t), y(t)) = \left(\frac{1+t}{a t^4}, \frac{1 + t}{a t^3} \right). \tag{2}$$  Since $a$ is just a scaling constant, it does the same thing as in the folium example, so for simplicity let us assume $a = 1$.  Then as before, $t = y/x$ implies that $t$ is a slope parameter.  However, unlike the folium, here the parametrization is undefined when $t = 0$.

When $t > 0$, it's clear that $(x(t), y(t))$ lies entirely in the first quadrant.  Moreover, as $t \to 0^+$, we see that $(x(t), y(t)) \to (\infty, \infty)$, but because $y/x = t$, the curve actually approaches the positive $x$-axis.  This seems counterintuitive, but for example, $t = 0.01$ corresponds to $(x,y) = (1.01 \times 10^8, 1.01 \times 10^6)$.

As $t \to \infty$, we have $(x(t), y(t)) \to 0$, so the curve approaches the origin as the slope of the point approaches vertical.  So we know that there is no closed loop in the first quadrant, for $0 < t < \infty$.

There are no problematic cases when $-\infty < t < 0$ because the parametrization is smooth and well-defined on this interval.  But since $t = -1$ corresponds to $(0,0)$, we see that the curve must form a closed loop for the interval $-\infty < t < -1$, hence this loop occurs in the second quadrant (as $-\infty < x(t) < 0$ and $0 < y(t) < \infty$).  In fact, this loop has a maximum distance from the origin, corresponding to the solution of $\frac{d}{dt}\left[x(t)^2 + y(t)^2\right] = 0$, which is the unique real root of the cubic $$2t^3 + 3t^2 + 3t + 4 = 0,$$ or $$t = \frac{1}{2}\left( \sqrt[3]{-6 + \sqrt{37}} - \sqrt[3]{6 + \sqrt{37}} - 1\right) \approx -1.42944. \tag{3}$$

Therefore, for your curve, the appropriate interval of integration is $-\infty < t \le -1$.

**Addendum:**  See the following animated image for your curve.  The red ray sweeps out slopes from $-\infty < t < \infty$.

[image]